# Mapping user to userinfo when there are multiple user type

Tags: hibernate, database-design

I have a User domain class. It has two user types. One is `teacher`, other one is `student`. And it has two fields, one is `teacherInfo`, the other is `studentInfo`. Since `teacher` user has a lot of properties that are different from `student` user, I cannot combine them as `UserInfo`. Otherwise there will be a lot of empty fields.

So in hibernate, how should I map the relation. If I use `One-to-one`, it requires that both `teacherInfo` and `studentInfo` cannot be null. Thus, it does not make sense because teacher user should not have a `studentInfo` mapped with. `One-to-many` relation solves this problem, but it seems wired. I just cannot make a decision. Thanks.

```
public class User {

    private Integer id;
    private UserType;
    private TeacherInfo teacherInfo;
    private StudentInfo studentInfo;
}
```

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, one should introduce two subclasses of the (abstract) class User, Teacher  and Student, and then follow one of the recipes in http://www.dineshonjava.com/p/implementing-inheritance-in-hibernate.html#.Vv4XwfmLTZ4 , for example (or follow the original documentation for modelling class inheritance) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So in hibernate, how should I map the relation. If I use One-to-one, it requires that both teacherInfo and studentInfo cannot be null.

It is incorrect. `@OneToOne` association can be `null`. So you can use it

```
public class User {

    @OneToOne
    private TeacherInfo teacherInfo;

    @OneToOne
    private StudentInfo studentInfo;

}
```

You can use `@Embedded`

```
public class User {

    @Embedded
    private TeacherInfo teacherInfo;

    @Embedded
    private StudentInfo studentInfo;

}
```

Even such approach `@ManyToOne` or `@OneToOne`

```
class Teacher {

        @ManyToOne
        private User user;  

}

class Student {

        @ManyToOne
        private User user;  

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. By "One-to-one, it requires that both teacherInfo and studentInfo cannot be null", I mean I am using lazy loading strategy. It requires one-to-one relation both to not be null. This is my annotation in user class: @OneToOne(optional=false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)

Comment: @Tong Don't use `optional=false`. Just `@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)`

Comment: If I don't use that hibernate will generate three sql, for user, studentInfo and teacherInfo. If I use that, there will only be one joined sql. I think that improves the efficiency. is't it?

Comment: @Tong I am not sure about _three sql_. Anyway you can use HQL (or SQL) with joins and projections.

Comment: Actually I did that. Like this: Query userQuery = currentSession().createQuery("from User u LEFT JOIN FETCH u.studentInfo where u.email = :email");                  It works. But If I use join fetch within hql, I end up with writing more hql code. I would like to put these in annotation, so I used optional = false, and @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)

Comment: I understand it now. either I can use HQL with joins, or I can use FetchMode.JOIN with criteria, since HQL does not work with fetchmode.